# NSDictionary containing several objects belonging to a hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, nsdictionary

I have a class called `A` and three subclasses of A: `SubA0, SubA1, SubA2`. I need a dictionary to contain these objects and I create it this way:

```
NSDictionary* dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   [[SubA0 alloc]init], @"SubA0",
                   [[SubA1 alloc]init], @"SubA1",
                   [[SubA2 alloc]init], @"SubA2", nil];
```

In the class `A` there's a method:

```
-(void)theMethod{
    NSLog(@"theMethod - Class A");
}
```

This method is overridden in all of the three subclasses:

Class SubA0:

```
-(void)theMethod{
    NSLog(@"theMethod - Class SubA0");
}
```

Class SubA1:

```
-(void)theMethod{
    NSLog(@"theMethod - Class SubA1");
}
```

Class SubA2:

```
-(void)theMethod{
    NSLog(@"theMethod - Class SubA2");
}
```

In my `ViewController`, this line of code:

```
[[dic objectForKey:classIdentifier]theMethod];
```

always call the method in the super class, but clearly I don't want this. I'd like the system to call the right method according to the class type.

Is this issue related to the `objectForKey:` method belonging to the NSDictionary? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati this isn't what is causing the problem, the question clearly states that the superclass implementation is being called when it should be calling the subclass implementation.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati: I don't understand your answer. The problem is that when I call theMethod on an object extracted from the dictionary, this object is always considered an A object. This is wrong, because all of the objects in my dictionary are of type SubA0, SubA1, SubA2...

Comment: Ignoring the typos in the question (the : at the end of the method signature results in a compiler error) I have not been able to reproduce this issue. Can you post the actual code you are using? Also I'd suggest moving towards [modern subscripting syntax](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/) rather than the cumbersome dictionary initialisation and objectForKey: methods.

Comment: @superpuccio Show us your custom initializers if any, explain the return types as you understand it.

Comment: @superpuccio the code in the question will call the subclass implementation. So there's a problem elsewhere. Can you post your actual code, or double-check the question against your actual code?

Comment: Cannot reproduce... [Here is a minimal example](https://gist.github.com/alladinian/e3aa1d7469828c5d3bd2) that works as expected

Comment: Works well with my test.So,you need to post full code to make it clear

Comment: Thank you, as soon as I can, I'll post my initializers!

Comment: oh sorry but it's my misunderstanding ! and your code is working fine for me! so if you override init method than may be there is some mistake by you!

Comment: I suspect that the value of classIdentifier is not what you think it is.

Comment: The problem was in my custom initializers. Check out my answer here below (I'll write it in a moment). Thank you all for led me to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my custom initializers. The class `A` has two init method:

```
-(instancetype)init;
-(instancetype)initWithAParam:(Param *)defaultParam;
```

And the implementation was:

```
-(instancetype)init{
    return [[A alloc] initWithAParam:0];
}
-(instancetype)initWithAParam:(Param *)defaultParam{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        _param = defaultParam;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Clearly, when I write:

```
[[SubA0 alloc]init];
[[SubA1 alloc]init];
[[SubA2 alloc]init];
```

the system calls the `super init` and this method returns an `A` object. To solve the issue simply rewrite the `init` this way:

```
-(instancetype)init{
    return [self initWithAParam:0];
}
```

Thank you all!